# Running two arrays in 1 foreach loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

I'm attempting to create a script which'll pull two csv files and run through both of them to create changes to AD attributes

My goal is to use `Set-ADUser <username> -replace @{extensionAttribute1=<Syntax>}`

the two csv's will replace

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    {

       $export = Set-ADUser <username> -replace @{extensionAttribute1=<Syntax>}

    }
}
```

I know how to set this up if only using 1 array, what would be the best way to use two arrays?

Comment: if the CSV files have the same structure, you can simple read them into one $Var and then run your loop on that. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `Import-Csv` twice then :)

```
$users = @(
    Import-Csv file1.csv
    Import-Csv file2.csv
)

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Set-ADUser $user.username -replace @{extensionAttribute1='some value'}
}
```

The above assumes that both files have a `username` column containing the user name

Answer (score 0):

This will import multiple csv files, and merge them into an array of pscustomobjects with properties

```
import-csv file1.csv,file2.csv
```

Comment: `Import-Csv` doesn't support import of multiple files at once

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It certainly works for me.  -path is a string array in the docs.

Comment: Looks like you're right, globbing got the better of me :)